EditForm.OnValidSubmit called 4 times in rapid succession
We have one user this is happening with. They are using a ChromeBook. We cannot reproduce it and it is not happening to any others. And it has happened to them twice out of 8 uses of the relevant page. Needless to say, I can't create a MVE because we can't reproduce it.
The page (relevant parts) is:
@page "/Account/UserProfile"
@attribute [Authorize]
@inherits ExPageBase
@implements IDisposable

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmitAsync" Context="EditFormContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <CustomValidation @ref="_customValidation" />
    <DxFormLayout>
        <DxFormLayoutItem ColSpanMd="12">
            <DxButton Text="Save Changes to Profile"
                      Id="save"
                      SubmitFormOnClick="true"
                      Enabled="SubmitEnabled"
                      RenderStyle="@ButtonRenderStyle.Primary" />
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
    </DxFormLayout>
</EditForm>

private async Task HandleValidSubmitAsync(EditContext editContext)
{
    if (LoggerEx.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
        LoggerEx.LogDebug($"User {User.Email} is updating their account.");
    try
    {
        SubmitEnabled = false;
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        SubmitEnabled = true;
    }
}

And the log shows:
Debug 16:09:12.139 [dw0sdwk00065I]-[user@mail.com] LouisHowe.web.Pages.Account.UserAccountProfile - User user@mail.com is updating their account.
Debug 16:09:12.150 [dw0sdwk00065I]-[user@mail.com] LouisHowe.web.Pages.Account.UserAccountProfile - User user@mail.com is updating their account.
Debug 16:09:12.160 [dw0sdwk00065I]-[user@mail.com] LouisHowe.web.Pages.Account.UserAccountProfile - User user@mail.com is updating their account.
Debug 16:09:14.435 [dw0sdwk00065I]-[user@mail.com] LouisHowe.web.Pages.Account.UserAccountProfile - User user@mail.com is updating their account.

The user says they clicked submit once. We've tried everything we can to reproduce it with no luck.
When this happens it is causing an exception in the EntityFramework save of the data due to duplicates in collections of the user model object. This makes me think somehow the PageModel object is the same for all these calls, and that is then updating the underlying EF model object with the same collection items on each call, thereby placing duplicates in it.
How could the OnValidSubmit be called repeatedly in quick succession?
Update: MrC suggested it might be the DxButton. I looked at the html  that generated and it's:
<button class="dxbl-btn dxbl-btn-primary dxbl-btn-standalone" id="save" type="submit">
   <span class="dxbl-btn-caption">Save Changes to Profile</span>
</button>

So I don't think DxButton is the issue.
Update: As requested, here's the relevant code from ExPageBase.
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    // This will:
    // 1. Initialize Principal.
    // 2. Assign the logged in user to the User property.

    Principal = (await AuthenticationStateTask).User;

    LoggerEx = await ScopedLoggerFactoryEx.GetLogger(GetType());

    var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(Principal);

    // when they login, we don't know it. And there are other minor cases where we don't know
    // that these settings have change. And this is an incredibly lightweight call. So we always
    // call this
    if (SessionData.ShowAnything || !SessionData.DataInitialized)
        SessionData.Reset(user);

    if (user == null)
    {
        SessionData.AnonymousUser ??= AppUser.CreateAnonymous();
        User = SessionData.AnonymousUser;
    }
    else
        User = user;
}


how do you set SubmitEnabled value? because as I can see, you are logging at the very beginning before disabling the button

@MohammadAghazadeh Sorry - I added that. It stops multiple clicks on the submit button. It is initially set to true at the end of OnInitializedAsync(). thanks

The user says they clicked submit once. - but you get four submits.  Faulty mouse?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Possible but very unlikely. I tried clicking rapidly and the SubmitEnabled var stopped that. In addition lots of his submits called it once. thanks

I've just reviewed the EditForm codebase to see if there's any paths that could lead to your problem, but can't see any.  I'm therefore erring towards some misbehaviour in DxButton.  Thats a closed book, so can you use a standard button instead to test?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Good idea - I'll try that. I'll update here once I have.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I went and looked at the raw html (much faster than revising the code and pushing it to dev, then swap to production). And it is a simple <button> element that I believe is correct. I updated the question with it. TIA

@DavidThielen Does it cause four submits every time?

@SurinderSingh It is calling the method HandleValidSubmitAsync() 4 times. I do not know if EditForm is doing that directly or something else is making the additional calls. But the method is never called directly and is only referenced in OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync".

@SurinderSingh sorry, I answered incompletely. Once it called 4 times, twice 2 times, and then 5 times it called it correctly once.

@DavidThielen could you please share code in ExPageBase

@SurinderSingh Added. HTH - thanks

I have one thought, have you tried to set a state flag to manage form submission more effectively. What I mean is, if the submit button can be disabled immediately upon submission. This prevents any further submissions until the current process completes. As its intermittently happedning so hard to reproduce.

@MdFaridUddinKiron I do disable the button immediately. But that's different than ignoring calls to the handler - I don't do that. I want to figure out why this is happening as it could manifest itself on every page.

I got your point, but did you able to notice in which scenario it usually do this behavior.

@MdFaridUddinKiron The scenario is one specific user has this happen. No one else. And the QA person tried to duplicate this and was not able to. So the scenario is this one chromebook where it happens sometimes.
